# rewrite rule to redirect to the most recent date permalink

Tags: permalinks, hooks, rewrite-rules

I've got an archive that's displayed using a URL on the form `www.mysite.ex/mycpt` and I need to make a rewrite rule for that URL which redirects to a permalink with the latest date archive, which is on the form `www.mysite.ex/mycpt/2012/01/31`. The archives use the same archive-mycpt.php template, but my guess is that the fact that it is a Custom Post Type does not matter in this case.

I can get the most recent post date by using get_posts and extract the `post_date` for the `post_type` and use that info to attach a path to the above mentioned URL. I suppose I could put that in a rewrite rule, but how do I make a rewrite rule that always has up-to-date information on the most recent post date?

I think that I might need to make an action hook somewhere to update the rewrite rule when a new post of the `post_type` is made, but I'm not sure which hook to use and how to use it, or if it's a good approach to begin with.

Any ideas?

edit: Thanks to woony for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good approuch.
I think it's best to redirect your page at mycpt. let it get the last date in php using your get_posts. And let the page redirect to where you need to be. 
Don't go auto updating your .htaccess, that's not what it is made for.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you suggest to redirect in the archive-mycpt.php template? Can that be done if the same template is used to display the date archives? Maybe a condition could be used.

Comment: Yes, you could, if I understand your question correct.
You can easily add any condition. Depending on your needs. 

Maybe you should try to make your initial question a little bit more clear. 
You want your archive to go to the last one yes?

Comment: I did as you suggested and made a redirect in the archive template based on a condition. I'll post my solution below.

Comment: alright. up me one if you like

Comment: doing redirection within a template is a waste of resources, use an action hook *before* the database is queried, like `parse_query` or `pre_get_posts`. see [action reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) in codex. you also avoid headers already sent errors that will encounter if any output reaches the browser before redirection.

Comment: Thanks Milo. It was my initial idea to use an action hook, but it's not clear to me which one to use and how to do it. I posted my solution below. How could I adapt it to an action hook approach?

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of my Custom Post Type archive I added this code:

```
<?php 
    if (!is_date()) { // redirect mycpt archive page to the most recent post date page

        wp_safe_redirect(seron_get_most_recent_mycpt_link());
        exit;
    }
?>
```

A also added this function to the functions.php file:

```
/**
* Genrate a URL for the most recent mycpt post date.
*/
function seron_get_most_recent_mycpt_link() {

    $latest_post = get_posts(array('numberposts' => 1,
                                   'orderby' => 'post_date',
                                   'order' => 'DESC',
                                   'post_type' => 'mycpt')
    );

    $date = explode(' ', $latest_post[0]->post_date);
    return home_url() . '/mycpt/' . str_replace('-', '/', $date[0]);
}
```